# How to loop this program 3x for my Salary Calculator Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, javahelp

So I’m trying to write a Java program that displays 3 employees gross pay factoring in overtime pay. I was able to make a program with a while loop but am confused as to get this to print for each employee. I want the output to look like “Pay for employee 1 is:…” “Pay for employee 2 is:…” “Pay for employee 3 is:…” the program I made looks nice but can’t make it for 3 employees. I played around with the increment operators and still got lost please help. I wrote it like this:(yes Java until scanner was activated)

```
System.out.print(“Enter hourly rate”);
Int hourlyRare = input.nextInt();
System.out.print(“Enter hours worked”); 
Int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();

While (hoursWorked <=40)
System.out.printf(“Pay for     employee one is: “ + hoursWorked * hourlyRate);

If (hoursWorked >40)
System.out.printf(“Pay for employee one is:” + hourlyRate * 1.5 * hoursWorked);
```

Output is:

Enter hourly rate: 33
Enter hours worked: 55
Pay for employee one is: 2722.5

I tried to use the whole loop and an of statement and I got stuck on how to get output for 3 employees. I’m not sure how to do increments correctly or if that is needed? Or did I mess this up entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap the whole thing in a loop. Since you know exactly how often you want the code to be ran you can just use a for-loop like this:

```java
for (int employer = 1; employer <= 3; employer++) {
    // ask for their rate and hours
    System.out.print(“Enter hourly rate”);
    int hourlyRare = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print(“Enter hours worked”); 
    int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();

    // print them using the employer-variable from the for loop
    System.out.printf("Pay for employer %d is: %f", employer, (hourlyRare * hoursWorked));
}
```

Inside the for loop you (usually) create a variable (called employer here) and initialize it (1 here). Then you specify a condition that has to be fulfilled for the loop to run (employer <= 3) and then an expression that is executed after each run of the loop (employer++) which is usually ment to make sure the loop eventually terminates. So the loop will run with employer = 1, then increase it to 2, run again, increase it to 3 and run again, after that it'll stop. Inside the loop is your code which asks them for rate and hours, and then prints out their number and pay. I've used `System.out.printf()` which is considered the cleanest way to print out a string containing different variables/results.

You can read about how to format Strings including variables in System.out.printf() here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html
And for more infos about the for loop check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html